# Tamanho de fontes, px ou pt?

Tags: css

Recebo o layout em PSD, exporto conforme minha necessidade. E faço `font-face` quando necessário.

O Photoshop que tenho, mostra a medida das fontes em **pt**, eu sempre apliquei **px** no CSS. Estava lendo [isso](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.pt_BR.html), e vi que ele trata de forma diferente essas duas medidas. E, as vezes, dependendo da fonte utilizada, tenho problemas com o tamanho. O ideal seria medir a font usada com o *crop* do Photoshop, ou algo do gênero? e designar em **pt** no CSS?

Comment: Dá uma lida aqui, explica legalzinho...http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

Comment: @Dante, o ideal então é _%_? desde que haja uma div com o tamanho total?

Comment: Se você souber exatamente qual o tamanho da div (Não for muito iterativa) e não tiver problemas com preenchimento total em alguns casos, melhor usar o '%'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sempre use px no css quando estiver usando valores absolutos, se quiser veja a tabela abaixo para fazer a substituição:

```
+---------+---------+----------+---------+
| Points  | Pixels  |   Ems    |    %    |
+---------+---------+----------+---------+
| 6pt     | 8px     | 0.5em    | 50%     |
| 7pt     | 9px     | 0.55em   | 55%     |
| 7.5pt   | 10px    | 0.625em  | 62.5%   |
| 8pt     | 11px    | 0.7em    | 70%     |
| 9pt     | 12px    | 0.75em   | 75%     |
| 10pt    | 13px    | 0.8em    | 80%     |
| 10.5pt  | 14px    | 0.875em  | 87.5%   |
| 11pt    | 15px    | 0.95em   | 95%     |
| 12pt    | 16px    | 1em      | 100%    |
| 13pt    | 17px    | 1.05em   | 105%    |
| 13.5pt  | 18px    | 1.125em  | 112.5%  |
| 14pt    | 19px    | 1.2em    | 120%    |
| 14.5pt  | 20px    | 1.25em   | 125%    |
| 15pt    | 21px    | 1.3em    | 130%    |
| 16pt    | 22px    | 1.4em    | 140%    |
| 17pt    | 23px    | 1.45em   | 145%    |
| 18pt    | 24px    | 1.5em    | 150%    |
| 20pt    | 26px    | 1.6em    | 160%    |
| 22pt    | 29px    | 1.8em    | 180%    |
| 24pt    | 32px    | 2em      | 200%    |
| 26pt    | 35px    | 2.2em    | 220%    |
| 27pt    | 36px    | 2.25em   | 225%    |
| 28pt    | 37px    | 2.3em    | 230%    |
| 29pt    | 38px    | 2.35em   | 235%    |
| 30pt    | 40px    | 2.45em   | 245%    |
| 32pt    | 42px    | 2.55em   | 255%    |
| 34pt    | 45px    | 2.75em   | 275%    |
| 36pt    | 48px    | 3em      | 300%    |
+---------+---------+----------+---------+
```

[Fonte](http://reeddesign.co.uk/test/points-pixels.html)

Comment: Entendi, então devo usar o _crop_ do Photoshop e medir o tamanho da font em PX? assim como faço com os outros elementos.

Comment: Acredito que pode salver essa tabela como referência, assim sequer precisará de ficar medindo. (Acho bem improvável que precisará de algo maior que `48px`)

Comment: Show de bola cara, muito obrigado. Você tem a fonte dessa tabela?

Comment: Ops, achei que havia adicionado na resposta... (agora está lá).

Comment: *"Sempre use px no css"*, e porque isso?

Comment: Digamos que talvez não fui claro o suficiente. Meu objetivo era dizer: **sempre use px para valores absolutos** (em vez de pt/cm/etc) pois os mesmos não são tão bem estabelecidos no css.

Comment: Eu lembro que antigamente, nos tempos do IE6 e talvez 7, o `px` era mal-visto pois impedia zoom do texto com `CTRL`+`+`. Também lembro de recomendarem não usar `px` em folhas de estilo para impressão. Resultado: hoje fico meio perdido com isso, não sei o que vale e o que não vale, e por que.

Comment: Não seria mais fácil usar diretamente o `pt`?

Comment: não, o recomendado é: `%` ou `em` para textos convencionais. `px` para valores absolutos onde necessário (imagens e lugares que *precisam* de valores absolutos para não quebrar o layout). E `pt` para impressão e somente para isso.