# Função para converter o tamanho das letras em SASS

Tags: sass

Bom dia, gostaria de saber como fazer uma função dentro do SASS que receba um valor em `pt` e converta para `px`. Sei que existe uma conta específica para a conversão e também que pode-se usar um `function()` mas será que é possível fazer uma função padrão para essa conversão de `pt` para `px`? Se sim, como posso fazer ou começar?

Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27133

Comment: Cara, da uma olhada nisso: https://www.sitepoint.com/converting-typographic-units-sass/ talvez te ajude, tem uma função ali que faz essa conversão, em relação ao padrão acho difícil pois cada fonte tem suas próprias dimensões.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solução retirada de [Converting Your Typographic Units with Sass](https://www.sitepoint.com/converting-typographic-units-sass/):

```
@function convert($value, $currentUnit, $convertUnit){
   @if $currentUnit == px{

      @if $convertUnit == ems{
        @return $value / 16 + 0em;
      }
      @else if $convertUnit == percent{
        @return percentage($value / 16);
      }

   }@else if $currentUnit == ems{

      @if $convertUnit == px{
        @return $value * 16 + 0px;
      }
      @else if $convertUnit == percent{
        @return percentage($value);
      }

   }@else if $currentUnit == percent{

      @if $convertUnit == px{
        @return $value * 16 / 100 + 0px;
      }
      @else if $convertUnit == ems{
        @return $value / 100 + 0em;
      }

   }@else if $currentUnit == pts{

      @if $convertUnit == px{
        @return $value * 1.3333 +0px;
      }
      @else if $convertUnit == ems{
        @return $value / 12 + 0em;
      }
      @else if $convertUnit == percent{
        @return percentage($value / 12)
      }

   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Utilize no SCSS:

```
$browser-context: 16; // Default

@function em($pixels, $context: $browser-context) {
  @return #{$pixels/$context}em;
}
```

Utilização da function em():

```
h1 {
  font-size: em(32);
}

p {
  font-size: em(14);
}
```

O resultado do CSS será:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
}

p {
  font-size: 0.875em;
}
```

Fonte: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/px-to-em-functions/